# Compiler reordering section with mutual exclusion

Tags: rust, concurrency, mutex, instruction-reordering

Since rust applies the mutex as a container/owner of its data and doesn't use an external guard like C++, I was wondering whether the rust compiler might reorder the internal part of the loop in the following pseudo-code (and by doing so, invalidate it..) and if so, how can I prevent it?

```
let mut some_type = SomeType::new();
let mut my_lock = MyLock::new();
(0..n).par_iter().for_each(|| {
     my_lock.lock();
     do_some_stuff_with(&mut some_type);
     my_lock.unlock();
})
```

Comment: This code wouldn't past Rust's borrow checker. Since the closure passed to `ParallelIterator::for_each` is sent to multiple threads, it must be `Fn`, which means it cannot capture `some_type` mutably. Therefore `&mut some_type` wouldn't compile.

Comment: AFAIK the reason it doesn't get reordered is that acquiring/releasing a lock defines a critical section, and the compiler/processor aren't allowed to move code out of a critical section. Using atomics with orderings other than `Relaxed` can also define a critical section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rust actually [uses the same memory model as C++20](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/atomics.html). So AFAIK you can protect *code* with a lock, it's just not a great idea (because nothing actually precludes unsynchronised access to the shared resource, and there usually is one you want to protect anyway), and also a bit error prone as you need to ensure you're keeping the mutexguard alive.

I really don't see the point here:

```py
let mut my_lock = Mutex::new(SomeType::new());
(0..n).par_iter().for_each(|| {
     let mut some_type = my_lock.lock().unwrap();
     do_some_stuff_with(&mut some_type);
})
```

and of course the `par_iter` is completely useless since: you're locking the entire callback, so you're just doing a linear iteration, except non-sequential and with a ton of overhead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, It's good to know it's possible, even if for most cases it's not ideal.